# async mongodb call with for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to update multiple documents so I have to use loop but below code is broken because it has multiple res.json.

```
for (i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i ++ ) {
      Trucks.update({ 'data.date': dateArray[i] }, {'$set': update}, {'multi':true}, function(err,response){
        res.json(response);
      })
  }
```

I can put res.end() but I want to know when the operation is done.

How can I use async module to improve it? I want to know when the operation is done.

Comment: Would you mind using another library bluebird and promises instead of callbacks? If so, this can be easily done...let me know.

Comment: @NidhinDavid I found a solution, just use `async.forEach` in async npm

Answer (score 0):

I don't whether it's good solution. It's just a hack.

I think it serves your need. Good luck.

```
var docsUpdated = 0;
var length = dateArray.length;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  Trucks.update({
    'data.date': dateArray[i]
  }, {
    '$set': update
  }, {
    'multi': true
  }, function(err, response) {
    if(err) res.end();
    docsUpdated += response;
    if( i === length-1){
      res.json(docsUpdated);
    }
  })
}
```